# AdMob Unity 5.3 integration error: File not found

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, google-play-services

I have done everything perfectly as described here https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/unity/start1
I have proper components in SDK manager.
I have imported:
Unity AdMob SDK
Google Play Games SDK for Unity
Had some errors, cleared them all after spending a lot of time.

After all this, I get this damn error:
"File not found: support-v4-.pom" 
I cannot solve this error. 
And it is annoying me as hell.
Can I please get some help?
Note: That update was installed, still problem exists.

Unity log image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zy4p3.png

SDK manager screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDG7z.png